# SQL conditional variables in select query

Tags: sql, sql-server, greatest-n-per-group, nested-sets

I'm trying to write an SQL query that uses the [Nested Interval Hierarchy](https://vadimtropashko.files.wordpress.com/2011/07/ch5.pdf) database model.

```
--Given a parent Id, this query retrieves the position of the youngest child which can be inserted into the table
SELECT TOP 1
    --compute values based on the youngest "sibling id" (the one with the highest value)
    (parent.m_11 * (FLOOR(child.m_11/child.m_12)+2) - parent.m_12) as m_11,
    (parent.m_11) as m_12, 
    (parent.m_21 * (FLOOR(child.m_11/child.m_12)+2) - parent.m_22) as m_21,
    (parent.m_21) as m_22
    FROM my_so_table child
        --grabs all children of the parent
        JOIN my_so_table parent
          ON parent.Id = 1
         AND parent.m_21 = child.m_22
         AND parent.m_11 = child.m_12
    --the operation "Floor(child.m_11 / child.m_12) is the siblingId that I need to do math on above
    ORDER By FLOOR(child.m_11/child.m_12) DESC
GO
```

With schema:

```
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[my_so_table](
    [m_11] [int] NOT NULL,
    [m_12] [int] NOT NULL,
    [m_21] [int] NOT NULL,
    [m_22] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL)
GO

INSERT INTO [dbo].[my_so_table] VALUES (2,1,1,0); --1.
INSERT INTO [dbo].[my_so_table] VALUES (3,1,1,0); --2.
INSERT INTO [dbo].[my_so_table] VALUES (3,2,2,1); --1.1
INSERT INTO [dbo].[my_so_table] VALUES (4,1,1,0); --3.
```

With the above schema, running the above query with parentId of `1` properly returns

```
5,2,3,1
```

which correctly represents the matrix of the new node to be inserted under the parent with Id of 1. Running the above query on parentId of `2` returns an empty list, when it should be returning

```
5,3,2,1
```

Representing the matrix of the first child under the parent with Id of 2.

This is wrong because my query is not handling the case that there are no children of parent. If there are no children of parent, the result of `Floor(child.m_11 / child.m_12)` should be -1. How do I alter my query to accomplish this?

Comment: What does "I know there are variables in T-SQL, but I am trying to write SQL-compliant code." mean? Are you trying to avoid variables or something under the guise that your code should be 100% portable? I am not at all clear what you are trying to do here.

Comment: "under the guise that your code should be 100% portable" yes. At least, that's the goal if it is possible. I'm a very naive SQL developer, so I'm not aware of SQL best practices. Setting a goal of having portable code seemed like a good idea.

Comment: Explicitly, if there are no children of parent, I need to use "-1" instead of "Floor(child.m_11/child.m_12)" in the select query. I do not know how to accomplish this.

Comment: Portability is a discussion well beyond the scope of here but honestly how often do you change database systems? :) As for your topic at hand we need to see some details more than just a query. Here is a great place to start.http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: Is that better? :)

Also, I'm not sure how to better phrase my question than "How do I alter my query to accomplish this". I hope to come up with a better way to ask this eventually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my solution. I was shying away from `greatest-n-by-group` when in reality I didn't understand how `group-by` worked.

```
--Given a parent Id, this query retrieves the position of the youngest child which can be inserted into the table
--insert into my_so_table(m_11, m_12, m_21, m_22)
SELECT TOP 1
    --compute values based on the youngest 'sibling id' (the one with the highest value)
    (parent.m_11 * (ISNULL(siblingId, 0) + 2) - parent.m_12) as m_11,
    (parent.m_11) as m_12, 
    (parent.m_21 * (ISNULL(siblingId, 0) + 2) - parent.m_22) as m_21,
    (parent.m_21) as m_22
    FROM my_so_table parent
        --grabs all children of the parent
        LEFT JOIN (
            --Grabs the youngest sibling for each sibling chain
            SELECT
                child.m_12,
                child.m_22,
                Max(Floor(child.m_11 / child.m_12)) as siblingId
            FROM my_so_table child
            Group By child.m_12, child.m_22
        ) child
        on(parent.m_21 = child.m_22)
        AND(parent.m_11 = child.m_12)
    WHERE parent.Id = @parentId
    ORDER By siblingId DESC
GO
```

`group-by` wasn't working before because I couldn't retrieve `m_12` and `m_22` from the child query, because I wasn't `group by`ing both values. Switching to left-join causes null values to be reported, which is exactly what I needed!